# Using find() in Excel to remove text from string

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm using find to remove some of the test string in lookup cell value

For instance I look-up the following in cell A2 `Application: sales_rep_support` and use find `=RIGHT(a2,FIND(" ",a2)+4)` to change it to `sales_rep_support`.

However I run into problems because I have other values that need parsed such as

```
Application: EComm_sk
Application: PG_Prescreen
Application: sales_rep_support
Application: Retention_sk

etc....
```

What I have been trying to accomplish is simply remove the `Application:` from the beginning of the string

I have also tried `left()` unsucessfully.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `SUBSTITUTE`.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A2,"Application: ","")
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I think that the simplest way is to use the Find & Replace on the column concerned if you intend to delete the original later on.

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
2. Find `Application:` ("Application", colon, space)
   Replace by nothing
3. In the Find & Replace window, click on <kbd>Options >></kbd> and make sure that the 'Within: ' is set to "Sheet" and that 'Match entire cell contents' is unchecked.

---

Otherwise, another function besides `SUBSTITUTE()` you can use is `MID()`:

```
=MID(text, start, length)
```

In your case, you can use:

```
=MID(A2, 14, LEN(A2))
```

Which will take everything from the character position 14 (After all the characters in "Application: ") to the end of the text. `LEN(A2)` is actually larger than the text you want, but that doesn't matter, it means it'll take everything till the end.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use `=REPLACE(A2,1,12,"")` this replaces characters 1-12 with "" (nothing) and so just displays the lookup `(A2)` from the 13th character, removing "Application:"

Answer (score -1):

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND(":",A2,1)))
```

Comment: It could be improved by adding a TRIM function to the answer as in above. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Answer (score -3):

Why on earth do you think `=RIGHT(A2,FIND(" ",A2)+4)`
is a reasonable way to call `RIGHT()`?  Where does the `4` come from? 
What does it signify?

The usage of `RIGHT` is

```
RIGHT(text, [num_chars])
```

i.e., the second parameter is the number of characters
that you want to extract.

Meanwhile, `FIND(" ", A2)` is the position of the first space in `A2`,
which is always 13 as long
as the first 12 characters are `Application:` and the 13th is a space. 
So `FIND(" ",A2)+4` is always 17;
you are always getting the 17 rightmost characters.

To get everything after the `Application:` , use

```
=RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)-FIND(" ", A2))
```

or simply

```
=RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)-13)
```